# SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, singleemailmessage, send-email

I have custom LWC page as Public Site, In my Page i will be collecting the Name and Email address, On clicking send will insert the data in Custom Object and will send an Email to an given Email address.

Email Template is configured as `Visualforce Email Template` Email Name is `Enroll`

When I click send email button from my Page I'm getting `System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id` following error.

```
try {
            emitcs1__Enrollment__c newEnrollment = new Enrollment__c (
                emitcs1__Family_Name__c = familyName,
                emitcs1__Family_Email__c = familyEmail,
                emitcs1__User__c = serviceCenterId
            );
            insert newEnrollment;

            Id enrollId = newEnrollment.Id;


            // get an email template
            EmailTemplate tpl = (EmailTemplate)[select Id   FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName ='Enroll' limit 1];
          //  EmailTemplate tpl = (EmailTemplate)[select Id   FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName ='Enrollment_Link' limit 1];

            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {familyEmail};
                String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {'myemailaddress@gmail.com'};
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();


            email.setTemplateId(tpl.Id);     
            email.setReplyTo('support@test.com');
            email.setSenderDisplayName('testing');        

            Contact con=[SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =:serviceCenterId limit 1];  
            email.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);
            email.setWhatId(enrollId); 
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            email.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
            email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
            email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            emailList.add(email);  

            List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
            if (results[0].success) {            
                newEnrollment.Status__c= 'Email Sent';
                Update newEnrollment;
                System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
            }else {
                System.debug('The email failed to send:  ' +  results[0].errors[0].message);
            } 
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('exception -->'  + e);
            return false;
        }
```

I have HTML Email template Name `Enrollment_Link` by Changing this Template in my code It's working. Both has referered to same fields and Objects.

**Debug Log**

```
14:49:43.0 (196648255)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[331]|e|Exception|true|false
14:49:43.0 (196811201)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[331]|e|"common.apex.methods.MessagingStaticMethods$EmailExecutionException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []"|0x206203be
14:49:43.0 (196831506)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[331]
14:49:43.0 (196838244)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[332]
14:49:43.0 (196848350)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[332]|Bytes:21
14:49:43.0 (196956008)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[332]|Bytes:139
14:49:43.0 (196983450)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[332]|Bytes:160
14:49:43.0 (197012130)|USER_DEBUG|[332]|DEBUG|exception -->System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
14:49:43.0 (197032576)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[333]
14:49:43.0 (197044203)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[333]|Bytes:5
14:49:43.0 (197062023)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|true
```

I tested From `Classic Email Templates` page by Clicking `Send Test and Verify Merge Fields`. It's working.

Comment: check if the user has access right to Enrollment__c and contact object. I think you forgot to set the template Id also email.setTemplateId(tpl.Id);

Comment: Yes the user has access right to Enrollment__c and contact object. Also  I missed to add `email.setTemplateId(tpl.Id);` here. It's already exist in my code

Comment: Have you checked if the user needs access through sharing rules or something for any of the objects mentioned in the `Enroll` template? Also, have you checked if the email templates are available to the public site?